# How to define few variables in one line in bash in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker

In my Dockerfile I am setting environmental variables one-by-one with structure like:

```
RUN export PATH="/root/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
RUN export RUBY_PATH="/root/.rbenv/shims/ruby"
```

Is there a way to merge this into 1 line, like

```
RUN export PATH="/root/.rbenv/shims:$PATH" && export RUBY_PATH="/root/.rbenv/shims/ruby"
```

?

Comment: `RUN export` is a no-op; each `RUN` command starts a new shell and environment variables aren't persisted beyond that.  You need `ENV` for this.  Better is to install things directly into the "normal" system paths, like have your interpreter be `/usr/bin/ruby`; since an image usually packages just one application, you don't need a tool like rbenv to manage multiple versions of an interpreter.

Comment: Came here for what David said. You can't define variables in bash in a Dockerfile *at all*, at least not ones that still have any meaning past the single RUN command in which they're defined.

Comment: agreeo with Devid, export does not persist ENV at all in docker, you have to use ENV. here is syntax with ENV. `ENV PATH="/root/.rbenv/shims:$PATH" RUBY_PATH="/root/.rbenv/shims/ruby"`